# Why is the network request failing but my browser loads the tile image just fine?

Tags: qt, networking

Here is a minimal working example of the problem.
Just update the pro file to `QT += core network gui`.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QObject::connect(&mgr,QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
            [=](QNetworkReply *reply){
        if ( reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) { qDebug()<<"reply errror:"<<reply->errorString(); }
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        QImage img = QImage::fromData(data);
//        img.save("C:/Users/ENTER_USERNAME_HERE/Desktop/tile.png");
    });
//    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://cartodb-basemaps-1.global.ssl.fastly.net/rastertiles/voyager/5/17/11.png"));
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/5/17/11.png"));
    mgr.get(request);
    return a.exec();
}
```

The `carto` request is working fine, but not the `openstreetmap` one. I get the error `Error transferring https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/5/17/11.png - server replied: Forbidden`. But displaying the tile in the browser is working. What could be the reason here? Is there any special data transmitted with the request that makes it fail?

Comment: Did you try it with http instead of https?

Comment: Yes, but makes no  difference.

Comment: perhaps `openstreetmap.org` have issue with your user agent. Can you try to mask yourself as sort of usual browser?

Comment: Yes meanwhile i found out the same, compared to another Qt map project with openstreetmap that just worked. You need to pass a user agent via `request.setRawHeader('User-Agent', userAgent_);` where `userAgent_` is some QByteArray string.